# Using Sage in a website that needs to be maintained by mere mortals

Tags: roots-sage

I am trying to help out an organization that hired some developers to create their website back in 2016, and the developers haven't touched the site since 2016.

I don't know enough about Sage to know if the developers really screwed things up, or if what they have done is the way things need to be done in Sage. One example of something that has me scratching my head (in between banging it on my keyboard): some page content - content that needs to be updated on at least a yearly basis - is hard-coded into template files, so that in order to update the information, you have to go in past the warnings about using the Theme Editor, figure out which included template contains the content, and update it there.

NOT something your typical office employee is likely to be able to do, yes?

My question is: is it even worth trying to keep this site running under Sage, or should I rebuild the site using a more user-friendly template? The site currently has fewer than 2 dozen pages plus a dozen or so posts and I would say is unlikely to get a whole lot larger, given the available resources.

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem to me doesn't seem to be so much about the Roots Sage theme framework, but that the developers didn't follow the most basic rules regarding WordPress theme development--separating the content from presentation. Hardcoding content into a template is just bad practice, and this would make any site difficult to edit no matter what framework it was built on.

If it's as simple as printing the content into a template so that page editor content changes can be reflected on the frontend, it may be a simple as adding `the_content()` to the corresponding page template overrides and removing the hardcoded content.

FWIW: Sage 8 templates are not that different from your standard WP templates, it's not using a templating engine like Blade, so you should be able to customize the templates if you're already familiar with standard WP templates.

So probably no need to burn it all down.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up finding a much more user-friendly (and usable) approach. But I am happy to hear that my opinion of the developers' approach was not too far off the mark.